# Xcode crashing after archive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, archive

App crashes after creating an archive of the app. My app works fine in several different branches of syncing, however, as soon as I create a Product-> Archive, after that has been completed, the app no longer runs and I receive "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" afterwards. This has happened on two different laptops. Even if I try to delete and re-download I get the same results.

To clarify, my issue does not happen while archiving. All of this happens after I archive the app.

Comment: Which Xcode version do you have? I remember that I have a similar issue, but after updating to the newest one it vanished.

Comment: @Sammy I have released to an app store prior to the archive.

Comment: @bazyl87 I am on Xcode beta 2 11.2

Comment: hey did you solve it? , i got the same issue

Answer (score -2):

Try to increase the version in the project settings to a higher number than the one released to app store
[image]