# Xcode crashing immediately after archiving

Tags: xcode11.3

This might be a duplicate of [Xcode crashing after archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937601/xcode-crashing-after-archive), but I did not see a satisfactory answer in that one.  I'm running xcode 11.3.1.  My app builds and runs in the simulator just fine.  However, when I do Product->Archive, the archive will supposedly complete successfully and then xcode immediately crashes with SIGABRT:

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSURL
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension
>   cannot be nil.

Screenshot of beginning of stack trace below -- any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Have you looked at Console.app output with timestamps near your time of crash?

Comment: Past solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548538/xcode-6-3-crash-while-archiving-a-project       (old project with some subprojects under source control while the main one is not)

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm!! I just disabled Source control in xcode preferences like the solution said, and it worked! Thank you!